# Python greater than or less than

Tags: python, if-statement, python-2.7

I have an 'if-elif-else' block and if a value is within that range it is assigned a certain value. However it when I run it just assigns it the value in the else block. This is my code:

```
if mile < 300:
    mileInfo['miles'] = 1
elif mile>=300 and mile <2000:
    mileInfo['miles'] = 2
elif mile>=2000 and mile <5000:
    mileInfo['miles'] = 3
else:
    mileInfo['miles'] = 4
```

Mile returns a float, but I thought that this didn't matter as much as in Java for example.

Thanks

Comment: What is ``mile``? What is ``mileInfo``? What is the output/error you get you don't expect?

Comment: As another note, Python supports 3-item comparisons, so you can do, for example, ``elif 300 <= mile < 2000:`` to simplify your code. That said, as you are in an ``elif``, it'll only run if the value is more than ``300`` anyway, so it's pointless to check again.

Comment: value is mile which is a float and it just assigns miles to value 4.

Comment: I'm not asking what type, I'm saying give us a runnable example with values that produce the problem you experience. Give us a value that when we do ``miles = x`` it has the problem you get.

Comment: after the `else`, include `print mile, type(mile)`, and see why you always get catched by the `else` in the first place. Are you sure `mile` is not always larger than 5000?

Comment: @heltonbiker Thanks for suggesting the type check. Mile is a str, I thought the result was a float.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe `mile` is a **string** containing a number? It will not be automatically converted.

```
>>> "1" < 100
False
>>> "1" == 1
False
```

You don't need to have the `elif` re-check that the previous `if` was false. If the value wasn't `< 300`, it is guaranteed to be `>=300`.

Comment: (+1) I like the way you're thinking

Comment: Thanks mile is a float returns a value eg. 325.0124. It returns the difference between two points. I initially had the code as less than 300 elif less than 2000 elif less than 5000. But that wasn't working either so I changed it to what I have now.

Comment: @user94628 please do a 'print type(mile)' and post the result as a comment.

Comment: Stuff like `"1" < 100` gives error in Python3. I suppose that's one of the things that they changed during the transition from Python2.

Answer (score 3):

The issue was that 'mile' was a string and as pointed out by other members string is not automatically converted. So I changed code to:

```
mileInt = int(float(mile))

if mileInt < 300:
    mileInfo['miles'] = 1
elif mileInt < 2000:
    mileInfo['miles'] = 2
elif mileInt < 5000:
    mileInfo['miles'] = 3
else:
    mileInfo['miles'] = 4
```

Using print type(mile) helps check what the type is.

Comment: Actually, `mileInt = int(mile)` should be enough. A pity that you unaccepted the earlier correct answer to just reiterate that it was correct.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse you're right, suggesting to check mile type was the solution to correcting my original code. I've accepted your answer in recognition of this. Thanks again for your help.